# vernemq authorization with mongodb configuration

Tags: mongodb, authentication, authorization

I'm configuring the vernemq and mongodb.
The steps I did was

1. created database 'verne' and collection 'vmq_acl_auth'
2. created user for verne db as follows

```html
<pre>
{
    "_id" : "verne.mqtt",
    "userId" : UUID("b6d8669a-99e0-4176-bce0-f5582fcb85c7"),
    "user" : "mqtt",
    "db" : "verne",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "verne"
        },
        {
            "role" : "read",
            "db" : "verne"
        }
    ],
    "mechanisms" : [
        "SCRAM-SHA-1",
        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
    ]
}
</pre>
```

3. created the mqtt client id / user id as below

   ```html
   <pre>
   {
   "_id" : ObjectId("5f3e57339388e2c423224efd"),
   "mountpoint" : "",
   "client_id" : "cli1",
   "username" : "user1",
   "passhash" : "$2a$08$uDq5UIcmQ34sdasfa3bsCZ3ixoXGH8VpTSSfRV5oNkgw/KrkDXXIGq",
   "publish_acl" : [
       {
           "pattern" : "a/b/c"
       },
       {
           "pattern" : "a/+/d"
       }
   ],
   "subscribe_acl" : [
       {
           "pattern" : "a/#"
       }
   ]
   }
   </pre>
   ```

But the vernemq is failing to query with this message.
**"not authorized for query on verne.vmq_acl_auth"**

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks
Yoonseok

Comment: Reference documentation you followed from the question.

Comment: There is no particular reference document to follow. I just gathered as much information as possible and came to this point.

Comment: MongoDB has documentation, so you should be following the steps outlined there for auth including verifying that you set auth up correctly. I assume vernemq also has some sort of documentation but I am not familiar with this library.

Comment: MongDB is working fine. I checked. The missing point is how to configure the vernemq to use the MongoDB.

Comment: I suggest investigating the documentation for that and adding it to the question once you find it.